# MySQL Orderby a number, Empty Strings (or 0's) Last

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Just asked a question pretty similar to this one...

Currently I am doing a very basic OrderBy in my statement.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE visible=1 ORDER BY position ASC, id DESC
```

The problem with this is that empty string entries for 'position' are treated as 0. Therefore all entries with position as empty string appear before those with 1,2,3,4. eg:

```
'', '', '', 1, 2, 3, 4
```

or:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Is there a way to achieve the following ordering:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, '', '', ''.
```

or:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0.
```

I assume the solution may have some kind of replace function but I am not able to find a function which does what I am after.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE visible=1 
ORDER BY 
    case when position in('', '0') then 1 else 0 end,
    position ASC, 
    id DESC
```

Comment: I think this will work but it's not the best solution. I think `position` should be an integer column ,and if that is the case, the `CASE` expression should use integers too, not strings. If `position` is not an integer or at least numeric, sorting as numbers won't work anyway. Also, this solutions adds a new column to sort for, which will likely have a negative impact on performance. If my assumption that `position` is actually an integer is correct, then the OP probably means `NULL` value where he wrote 'empty string', meaning you can simply write `ORDER BY COALESCE(position, ~0), id DESC`

Comment: @Roland: the OP implied pretty clearly that position is a string: *"The problem with this is that empty string entries for 'position' are treated as 0."*

Comment: OrbMan yes, he did. And I am saying that that is probably part of the problem. My suggestion was to give it a proper data type up front instead of trying to mop up afterwards.

Comment: @Roland: Oh, misunderstood you. I definitely agree with that! My assumption was that this was not an option, but definitely good to call it out.

Comment: I just want to ask if I used this technique would it still be able to use the index I defined on the column used on the case statement?

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo - I don't know if it will, EXPLAIN will tell you the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You might try a [CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html), like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE visible = 1
ORDER BY CASE position WHEN '' THEN '9999' ELSE position END CASE ASC,
    ID DESC
```

Comment: I realise this is an old answer, but it's just saved my butt. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 1):

You say that `position` contains empty string entries...Do you really mean empty string, or do you mean `NULL`? If it actually contains `NULL` entries, you should use a slight modification of Orbman's statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE visible=1 
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE(position, ~0)
,   id DESC
```

`COALESCE()` returns the value of the first argument that is `NOT NULL`. The ~0 is a piece of black magic that will get you the maximum integer value supported by MySQL. (~ does a bitwise negation, turning all 0 bits to 1). So, in this case, if `position IS NULL` is true, it will return `18446744073709551615`, else it will return the value of `position`.

I'd also like to point out that the data type of your `position` column should most likely be of some integer type (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html). Because you mention empty strings, I think you should check your table definition by doing `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>`. If position is not an integer type, I would advise you to change it. The main reason is that strings, even if they look like numbers, don't sort as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can trying joining two sub queries where one select id > 0 and not empty and the other select empty and 0 only