# MySQL: Get ordered records with row number

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Was trying to get the ordered result with row number in one the queries but unable to get expected result.

Problem:

I want to assign row number to ordered result (on sequence number other zero using logic found in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052216/mysql-orderby-a-number-empty-strings-or-0s-last))

While executing internal sub-query, am able to get the ordered result but when row number is assigned, the order changes.

So when I execute the entire query, it doesn't give the expected result.

SqlFiddle Link:
Please find the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35399f/9) for the same.

Expected Output:

```
rownum  sequenceno

    1   1
    2   2
    3   3
    4   0
    5   0
    6   0
```

Actual Output:

```
rownum  sequenceno

    1   0
    2   2
    3   0
    4   1
    5   0
    6   3
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, I limit by 6 since that is what you are asking for. You can offset by the id further if you need it for a between case eg `LIMIT 3,6` for id 3 to 9 for example. I also move the rowcount out from the subquery to the top query because you want the rows for the final product.

```
SET @rownum=0;
SELECT rownum, vehDetails.* FROM (
SELECT  @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rownum, vehDetails.*
    FROM    (   
            SELECT  
                    vehname
                    ,vehlastupdated
                    , vehicle.sequenceno
            FROM        vehicle 
            INNER JOIN  user ON vehicle.custno = user.custno 
            WHERE       user.userkey = '123456'
            AND         vehicle.custno = 1
            ORDER BY    (CASE WHEN vehicle.sequenceno = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        ,vehicle.sequenceno ASC

            ) vehDetails
    ) vehDetails
    WHERE vehDetails.rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 6
    ORDER BY    sequenceno = 0,sequenceno  ASC
```

If you need to do more things with your rownum,for example `rownum IN (1,4,10)`, you could do another subselect on this query here.

Comment: Thanks for response. Would not be able to add limit as it is existing SP which is used for pagination. Would try to put the rownum outside as suggested and get back.

Comment: Check my edit and see if that does it for you. Ive taken the limit out

Comment: Thanks @Octopi. Didn't know it would be just moving out the rownum outside the sub-query. Thanks a lot for the help. Updated fiddle with expected output: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35399f/29